# How to sent parameter as dynamic in this component?

Tags: react-native

Im almost new at React Native. Trying to make a component. How to sent paramter as title to this appbar component? thanks all...

i found some solutions. But that solutions contains another component types.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Appbar } from "react-native-paper";

export default class CustomAppbar extends React.Component {
render(title) {
    return (
        <Appbar.Header>
            <Appbar.BackAction  onPress={() => { }} />
            <Appbar.Content title={this.props.title} />

        </Appbar.Header>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

lemme know if any help is required

```
const MyComponent = () => (
  <Appbar.Header>
    <Appbar.BackAction onPress={() => {}} />
    <Appbar.Content title="Title" />
    <Appbar.Action icon="calendar" onPress={() => {}} />
    <Appbar.Action icon="magnify" onPress={() => {}} />
  </Appbar.Header>
);
```

Comment: i saw this and tryed. But when i call this component in app.js, app bar douesnt shown in simulator. Cause of it i use this method.

Comment: Oh! now working your method. I'll try to sent any parameter. Give me a sec...

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/props its helped me. Thank you for answer ill mark ass helpful your answer.